# Ubuntu - Patch Diff merge issue

Tags: patch, diff

i have two text files **test1.txt** and **test2.txt** with content as

```
 test1.txt
 1
 2

 test2.txt
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

what i have achieved with the txt files is a difference of both files in a third file as

> diff test2.txt test1.txt > test.patch
>
> patch test.txt < test.patch

in text.txt i have the resultant difference of both files.

Now i am doing the same with CSV files.

The format for CSV files is like

HENRY CONSTANTINE | 02256 | MEDICAL | Speciality

> diff small2.csv small1.csv > small.patch
>
> patch small.csv < small.patch

*Note: I have created the small.csv file manually.

But i get the following error when i run the patch

```
patching file small.csv
Hunk #1 FAILED at 1.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file small.csv.rej
```

Does anyone have any idea of how to achieve the above Difference file for CSV files.

Comment: This question really cannot be answered unless you post the files it applies to. You are doing the correct thing, but the it is entirely possible for a patch to fail to apply. As you show with the `test.txt` files, you are applying the patch to a different file than what you generated it from. Then it is possible that it doesn't apply cleanly, and you get a reject file to be able to fix it manually.

Comment: Thanks for editing and adding the test1.txt and test2.txt, but that doesn't help a lot because we still can't see what's failing. Can you add those too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include the file name information, use `-u` option:

```
diff -u test2.txt test1.txt > test.patch
```

In this case, you can use the below command:

```
patch -o test.txt < test.patch
```

If you return to the original contents, you can use the below command:

```
patch -R test.txt < test.patch
```

Comment: `diff test2.txt test1.txt > test.patch`

 `patch **test.txt** < test.patch`
i patch the result into a third file

Comment: The issue is with CSV files. TXT files work well

Comment: Can't it do by the same way? `diff -u small2.csv small1.csv > small.patch` and `patch -o small.csv < small.patch `.